# iframe content full loading in IE8 - IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a problem with page full loading in IE8-9. I want to do some actions after div content fully loaded, but in IE8-9, the page is not loading fully. Also, the action is not working correctly, because it should do some actions with loaded content.

Here is the small part of my code. I am trying to access iframe content and change style when iframe is fully loaded:

```
$('#simulator_content').load(function(){
  if($('.edit-but').hasClass('edit_css_click')){
     $('#simulator_content').contents().find('#inner__wp_cincopa_1').find('style').html($("#_skin_css_new").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i detect IE8 and 9 loading problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
// there might be any third party image / request that's why it taking so much time to load
// here is an alternate way to do that thing
// check selector ID name with closest one

function reCheckElem(){
    if($("#simulator_content").length>0){
        // now element is loaded / available to modify
        alert("Element is ready to modify!!");
    } else { 
        setTimeout(function(){
            reCheckElem(); // wait 0.5 second and check in again
        },500);
    }
}

// call it when page start loading
reCheckElem();
```

Comment: unfortunately this is gave me the same result :(